# How should I optimize this "needle in a haystack" code further?

Tags: javascript, optimization

**Backstory**

I have a set of data which is a list of product prices and a target number I need to come close to. I've theorized that the quickest way to do this is to generate every possible purchase set and then see which outcome is the closest to my target number.

eg.

- example data set: `$10, $5, $1`
- example target: `$12`
- boolean "possibles": `001, 010, 100, 011, 101, 110, 111`
- possible sums: `$1, $5, $10, $6, $11, $15, $16`
- the closest matching boolean set is `101` for `$11`

**Question**

Most data sets are minimal so using es6 is just fine.  As the data increases the processing time grows exponentially as expected. Short of choosing a different language, what advancements could I make to shave off time?

Here's the dataset that I'm currently struggling with:

- data: `[7524.00,1.63,2000.00,23794.00,0.01,330.00,462.00,858.00,5000.00,5250.00,23162.00,23804.00,5250.00,13376.00,0.06,0.08,4000.00,10000.00,166.56,12441.00,25.00,1000.00,20000.00,2000.00,20000.00,10000.00,5468.00,20000.00];`
- target `201887`

*code*

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6wzn1pa/83/)

```
let possibles = [];
let sums = [];
let target = 201887;
let data = [7524.00,1.63,2000.00,23794.00,0.01,330.00,462.00,858.00,5000.00,5250.00,23162.00,23804.00];//,5250.00,13376.00,0.06,0.08,4000.00,10000.00,166.56,12441.00,25.00,1000.00,20000.00,2000.00,20000.00,10000.00,5468.00,20000.00];

let rep = new Array(data.length).fill(1).join('');

let decMax = b2d(rep) + 1;

genPossibles(decMax, possibles)
.then(genSums()
.then(matchTarget()));

/****************
    functions
****************/

function d2b(d){
    return Number(d).toString(2);
}
function b2d(b) {
    return parseInt(b, 2);
}

function genPossibles(decMax, arr, start=0, runs=1000) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //console.log(decMax, arr.length, start, runs);
    for(let i = start; i < start+runs; ++i) {
      if(start+i > decMax) {
        possibles.pop(); // last item is useless
        console.log("possibles", possibles.length);
        resolve();
        return;
      }

      let binStr = d2b(i);
      possibles.push(binStr);
    }

    setTimeout(() => genPossibles(decMax, arr, start+runs), 0);
  });
}
function genSums(start=0, runs=1000) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for(let i = start; i < start+runs; ++i) {
      if(i >= possibles.length) {
        console.log("sums", sums.length);
        resolve();
        return;
      }

      let str = possibles[i];
      let sum = 0;
      str.split('').reverse().forEach((bool, j) => {
        if(bool == 1) sum += +data[j];
      });
      sums.push(sum);
    }

    setTimeout(() => genSums(start+runs), 0);
  });
}
function matchTarget() {
    let closest = {id:-1, bin: '', total:-1, diff:Infinity};
    sums.forEach((o, i) => {
      let d = Math.abs(target - o);
      if(d < closest.diff) {
        closest.id = i;
        closest.bin = possibles[i];
        closest.total = o;
        closest.diff = d;
      }
    });
    console.log("closest", closest);
}
```

*additional fyi*

I have the data commented out about half way until I figure out how to make this run quicker.

Comment: I'm not sure algorithimically how to do this, but _logically_ you can start to prune away certain options at certain thresholds.  For instance, is the sum for `011` already greater than the target price?  If so, then you certainly aren't going to get any closer with `111`.  Similarly, if `011` is already _below_ the target price then `010` and `001` can both be skipped.  Obviously, the challenging next step becomes encoding that in your script.

Comment: @AlexanderNied if you want to add this as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: In terms of the algorithm, you seem to be looking at a kind of [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). You can find more information about existing algorithms for problems in that space in that wikipedia article. Please [edit] your title to be more descriptive of your problem. "javascript how can I optimize this script" is way too broad. See also: ["_Should questions include "tags" in their titles?_"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/1266062)

Comment: For language optimizations, one good start would be to use a [typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) like `Float64Array` instead of a regular array.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "needle in a haystack". Rather it's a classical [discrete optimisation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_optimization), in particular [integer linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming). It is NP-complete and can be solved using branch-and-bound, branch-and-cut or dynamic programming.

Comment: @rainbow.gekota No, that may as well make it slower to run. You should use typed arrays only when dealing with binary data (byte buffers), e.g. when interfacing with lower-level systems.